grammar, usage この間
So, my thinking and question is that i know the basic difference between 間　and 間に. 間 is about the entire period of time - 寝ている間テレビが点いてた. And 間に is about some period during action - 寝ている間に電話があった.
So, what about grammar この間 with meaning the other day; lately etc. All the examples mean that regardless of the duration of the action there is always 間 without に.
このあいだ彼に会った。 I met him the other day, and talked for a couple of minutes/hours (or didn't talk). Why is there no に here if it means part of a period of time? there are no such distributions in this stable grammar "この間"? It is always clear without context whether there is に or not?

この間 is a fixed expression meaning "the other day". Since it's fixed, you have to memorize it as-is, and remember that it does not take any particle. When you use this expression, before worrying about に, even the meaning of この ("this") is obscure.

この間、彼に会った。
The other day, I met him.
(refers to a recent past event)

(Note that the English expression "the other day" is equally confusing to an English learner. What exactly does "the other" refer to? And why can't we say "on the other day" like we say "on the 10th" or "on Monday"?)
However, it's also perfectly fine to add に and say この間に. In this case, everything follows the standard grammar you already understand:

この間に彼に会った。
During this period/time/interval, I met him.
(この間に refers to some point during the period specified in the context, e.g., a short interval between classes)


so can i use it like duration? 彼はこの二日間ここにいました　?

@DmitriiHude Yes, that sentence is grammatically perfect and means "He was here for the past two days".
